# Cakephp contain inside another. It´s possible?

Tags: cakephp, controller, contains

I am trying to make a cotain inside another. it's possible?

```
  $tareasp = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas
   ->find('all',
            ['contain' =>
                ['Tareas'=>
                    ['contain'=>
                         ['Photos']
                    ]
                ]
            ])
  ->where(['proyecto_id' => $proyecto['id']]);
```

I tried it but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `contain` key multiple times, you can just nest the names:

```php
'contain' => [
    'Tareas' => [
        'Photos'
    ]
]
```

or use dot notation:

```php
'contain' => [
    'Tareas.Photos'
]
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)**